# Get results with MAX([Action Date]) per Cases

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, max

I would like to get your help in the following case:

I have three columns `[Case]`, `[Action Date]`, `[Person ID]` and I would like to get the maximum `[Action Date]` for each `Case` with the related `[Person ID]`

[image: Example]

As you can see the results for the `Case` are identical and we have the `[Action Date]` and `[Person ID]` which are not, I would like to get back the `MAX([Action Date])` (17-04-2020) and the related `[Person ID]`.

```
select 
   [Case], 
   MAX([Action Date]) as 'Last Parking Date',
   [Person ID]
from SOURCE_TABLE 
group by 
   [Case], 
   MAX([Action Date]) as 'Last Parking Date',
   [Person ID]
```

I tried to write it with subselects, but the code became totally confusing.

Thank you so much for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
SELECT [Case], [Person ID], [Action Date] AS [Last Parking Date]
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Case] ORDER BY [Action Date] DESC) rn
  FROM SOURCE_TABLE 
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick help! It worked and less confusing than the bunch of subselects! :)